# Postfix: 552 Requested mail action aborted: exceeded storage allocation

Tags: postfix

Running Debian 9 with Postfix 3.1.4.

When sending emails with attachments larger than default (10MB) to accounts on this server, the sender is getting: 
 552 Requested mail action aborted: exceeded storage allocation

My current running config:

```
# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 35720000
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = mail.example.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.net/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.net/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = ${message_size_limit}0
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Any ideas?

Log:

```
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: connection established
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: master_notify: status 0
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: name_mask: resource
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: name_mask: software
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2222]: rewrite stream disconnect
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: connect from mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_list_match: mail-wm0-f48.google.com: no match
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_list_match: 74.125.82.48: no match
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_list_match: mail-wm0-f48.google.com: no match
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_list_match: 74.125.82.48: no match
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: mail-wm0-f48.google.com ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 74.125.82.48 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: mail-wm0-f48.google.com ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 74.125.82.48 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: mail-wm0-f48.google.com ~? [::1]/128
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 74.125.82.48 ~? [::1]/128
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_list_match: mail-wm0-f48.google.com: no match
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_list_match: 74.125.82.48: no match
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: send attr request = connect
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: send attr ident = smtp:74.125.82.48
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: input attribute name: status
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: input attribute value: 0
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: count
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: input attribute name: count
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: input attribute value: 1
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: rate
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: input attribute name: rate
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: input attribute value: 1
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: input attribute name: (end)
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: > mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: 220 mail.example.net ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: < mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: EHLO mail-wm0-f48.google.com
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_list_match: mail-wm0-f48.google.com: no match
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_list_match: 74.125.82.48: no match
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: > mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: 250-mail.example.net
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: > mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: 250-PIPELINING
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: > mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: 250-SIZE 35720000
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: > mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: 250-VRFY
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: > mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: 250-ETRN
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: > mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: 250-STARTTLS
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: > mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: > mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: 250-8BITMIME
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: > mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: 250-DSN
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: > mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: 250 SMTPUTF8
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: < mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: QUIT
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: > mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48]: 221 2.0.0 Bye
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: mail-wm0-f48.google.com ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 74.125.82.48 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: mail-wm0-f48.google.com ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 74.125.82.48 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: mail-wm0-f48.google.com ~? [::1]/128
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 74.125.82.48 ~? [::1]/128
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_list_match: mail-wm0-f48.google.com: no match
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: match_list_match: 74.125.82.48: no match
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: send attr request = disconnect
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: send attr ident = smtp:74.125.82.48
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: input attribute name: status
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: input attribute value: 0
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: input attribute name: (end)
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: disconnect from mail-wm0-f48.google.com[74.125.82.48] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: master_notify: status 1
Jul 19 11:05:18 mail3 postfix/smtpd[2231]: connection closed
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
There was a smart firewall blocking attachments larger than configured.